# Tasksel deleted some desktop depedencies

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, php, backup, tasksel

I need help.

I tried to make upgrade from php5 tp php7 this morning on my local dev machine. I run tasksel to install lamp but unfortunetly I'm unchecked one of depedencies, probably for ubuntu-desktop which  someohow harmed O.S.  I tried to reboot o.s. , but do not work properly. How can I fix this, or atleast restore some of my data and reinstall os and make it work again. Also, have Windows 7 in dual boot if it means anything. Thank's

Comment: Do you still get a grub menu? Are you able to get to a terminal using CTRL + ALT + F1? If so, you could try: `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`. Alternatively, if you can get a terminal up, just run `sudo tasksel` again and select whatever you de-selected.

Comment: @VanessaDeagan Meanwhile, I found a tool ext2explore , which allowed me to read linux files from windows side, so I am  moved neccecary files to windows and I am about to make fresh installation of linux when grab some free time. Thanks anyway.